# Drupal and Email notifications

Tags: email, drupal

I encounter a weird problem with Drupal 6.x

When a user registers a new account no email notification is sent and by checking the sendmail log files there is no attempt to send an email.

When a user is deleted or publishes an article an email is sent successfully.

I can't find why this happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no email sent when a user logs in.

Do you have a rule for that or a custom module that should do that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant register not login